# Remove text by clicking on it - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to start learning react but fail understanding basic logic.
I have a todo list page, which works fine with a strike-through, but if I try to change the strike through to REMOVE instead, my app disappears on click.
Here's my code, hopefully you can understand:

```
function Note({ notes, note, onClickSetter }) {
    const { input, id } = note
    const [strikeThrough, setStrikeThrough] = useState(false);

    function onNoteClick(event) {
        const { value, id } = event.target
        //setStrikeThrough((prev) => !prev) - the strike through which is canceled right now
        onClickSetter(prev => prev.filter(aNote => aNote.id !== id)) // why this doesn't work?
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1 style={ strikeThrough ? {textDecoration: 'line-through'} : { textDecoration: 'none' }} id={id} onClick={onNoteClick}>{input}</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

a little explanation on my props:
notes - literally the list of notes which comes from a useState on father component (we shouldn't touch this from my understanding of react)

note - self note information

onClickSetter - the other part of useState, the setter one.

So on another words, I have the notes which holds all notes, and onClickSetter which is in another words is setNotes - both part of useState

on top of that I have a note information, because this is a note component

the father component:

```
function Body() {

    const [Notes, setNotes] = useState([])

    
    return (
        <div className='notes-body'>
            <NewNote onClickSetter={setNotes}/>
            {Notes.map((note) => { return <Note key={note.id} notes={Notes} note={note} onClickSetter={setNotes}/>})}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
function NewNote({ onClickSetter }) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('')

    function onInputChange(event) {
        const { value } = event.target
        setInput(value)
    }

    function onButtonClick(event) {
        onClickSetter((prev) => {
            try {
                return [...prev, {input: input, id: prev[prev.length-1].id+1}]
            }catch{
                return [{input: input, id: 0}]
            }
        })
        setInput('')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Input placeholder="add new note" className='note-text' onChange={onInputChange} value={input}/>
            <Button className='btn btn-primary add-note' onClick={onButtonClick} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: please post your other code also.

Comment: When your page goes blank -- please edit your question with the errors in the browser developer console :)

Comment: Actually as well as that, the NewNote code is also needed. Its possible the problem is ultimately that the code is inconsistent with the shape that is being pushed onto the notes array.

Comment: The code which doesn't work is inside onNoteClick, for this version of code there are no errors and the page stays the same, I apologize for the hassle. Basically I got a Notes-setNotes useState and I want to remove note when I click on it.

Comment: Sorry yes, I noticed that and edited my comment, my bad. Can we see NewNote? I know it seems orthogonal, but the data that is added to the array and the shape of it is relevant here

Comment: Added NewNote aswell! Again im very sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Not at all! Let me take a look

Comment: Cool, i got it, give me a few mins to put the answer together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `event.target.id` is a `string` representing a number since all HTML attributes has the string type. Whilst in your data structure, the ID is a `number`. So, e.g. `"1"` vs `1`. This can be hard to spot sometimes.

The easiest way to fix this is to add a `parseInt` to the right place to convert the string to a number:

```
  onClickSetter((prev) => prev.filter((aNote) => aNote.id !== parseInt(id)))
```

However, I also want to mention (and this is more advanced stuff but I like to get people on the right track) that really, you shouldn't pass the whole setter down into the child component, but instead a callback called something like `onRemoveNote` that accept the note id and the actual filtering/removal would happen in the parent component.

This would be better placement of concerns.

Comment: My god I can't believe it was that, it works now. Thanks a lot for your time and efforts, I appreciate it a ton. About the setter passing, I did that after I failed doing what I wanted to try another approach, I'll do my best to not make it a habit. For now I'm (very) satisfied, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Great, sounds good. If youre wondering how I found it, the easiest way is to log everything in the actual `filter` predicate: `prev.filter((aNote) => { console.log(aNote, id); return aNote.id !== parseInt(id)))`

Comment: Really, impossible to find the hack. Keep it up @AdamThomas

Comment: @AoXNeR would you mind marking this as the answer :D

Comment: Of course! New to stackoverflow so it flew out of my mind. Mega thanks for everything!